# Create and open event in different process

Tags: c, winapi, events, process

I am trying to synchronize two processes using events.

In the first process, I create an event, open second process, do some operations, signal event and wait for the second process. The second process tries to open the created event and wait for the signal, but at open process, I receive error code 2 = not found.

#### First process:

```
hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, L"MyEvent");
if (NULL == hEvent)
{
    __leave;
}
if(!CreateProcess(procPath, args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    __leave;
}

// Some minor changes

SetEvent(hEvent);

if (hEvent != NULL)
{
    CloseHandle(hEvent);
}
WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, 60000); // wait 60 seconds
```

#### Second process:

```
hEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, L"MyEvent");
if (NULL == hEvent)
{
   LOG_ERROR(L"[%d] OpenEvent MyEvent\n", GetLastError());
   return;
}
WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 10000);
```

Comment: You can't call CloseHandle() like that, the child process never has a chance to see it.  Moving it after the WaitForSingleObject() call is the obvious and correct solution.  Albeit that 60 seconds is a blind guess as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the `CloseHandle` call after the `WaitForSingleObject` call.

This way, your second process will have opened the event before the first process close it.

If you don't do this, the first process may close the event before the second process open it, and the system will destroy the event because it has no opened handle anymore. The second process will then report that the event don't exist.

Also, your first process could use `INFINITE` rather than 60 seconds.

Comment: Thank you. I have moved the CloseHandle and now it works fine. I can't wait INFINITE for the second process to end, I can't risk to be stucked in that wait. In case the timeout is reached, I know how to continue my work, but thank you for your tip. :)

Comment: Would it be different if calling `CreateEvent` twice instead?